# How to call a protocol method in another class

Tags: objective-c, ios, protocols

Say for example i have declared a protocol in one class and i want it to be called in different classes. Is it possible.

```
@protocol testProtocol
@required

- (void) showTestProtocol:(Call *)callObject;

@end

@interface TestClass1 : UITableViewController {
        id<testProtocol> delegate;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
```

in Implementation class

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Actually another Class has the definition of the method declared in the protocol. Now how can i use this protocol in another class to call that method?. I need all the other classes should use this method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get it, which object should call which method on which object? On an class that confirms to a protocol, you can call that method from the protocol like the class defined this method it self.

Comment: I don't think you fully and correctly understand the concept of protocols. Please read the Apple developer documentation and rewrite your question more clearly.

Comment: Also make sure you are not creating a retain cycle by retaining a delegate - commonly a delegate is assigned and not retained!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the methods declared in this protocol from another class (say ClassA), you to first import the header file (.h) in which this protocol is defined. And then, ClassA has to conform to the protocol. In case you want all classes to be able ti implement this method, and you don't want to explicitly confirm to this protocol, then you should probably be looking into using the informal protocol which use categories.